# Accessing a function (from another file) inside an anonymous function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to access a function from another file. That function is wrapped in an anonymous function (module.exports).

```
// main.js

    const testFile = require('./testFile')

    console.log(testFile.test())
    // returns testFile.test is not a function
```

```
// testFile.js

    module.exports = (app) => {
         function test(){
              return "Hello there"
         }
    }
```

Comment: You can't do that without changing the other file.

Comment: @str so you're saying something along the lines of-  const test = () => { return "hello there" } module.exports = { test } ?

Comment: There are several issues there. First, in the testFile.js file, the first function is not returning the `test` function, making it innaccessible to anything outside the anonymous function's scope. Then, in the main.js file, what you call `testFile` is actually the anonymous function.

Comment: @Seblor I think i'm on the right track. So what youre saying is - return function test(){} will give access to everything outside the scope of the anonymous function. Then, when I call the anonymous function ( what I call testFile), the test function will be invoked which will then return "hello there"? Is that right?

Comment: You're missing a step. calling the anonymous function will only return the `test` function, that you will then need to call.